# NHibernate: Create criteria from subquery

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Have SQL:

```
select COUNT(1) from
(SELECT TOP 10 Status
FROM SESSIONS
where SERVER_ID = 2569
ORDER by ID desc) as s
where s.STATUS = 32768
```

How do I create Criteria in NHiberbate? Language C#.

```
        var subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Session))
            .SetProjection(Property.ForName("Status"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Server", server))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
            .SetMaxResults(10);
        var query = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Session))
            .Add(Subqueries.Exists(subQuery))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status.Id", valueFailStatus))
            .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            return (int)query.GetExecutableCriteria(session)
            .UniqueResult();
```

But I get a sample of the entire table, and not one of those 10 elements.

Answer (score 4):

Right now your query says *Get me `Session`s with `StatusId` of `valueFailStatus` as long as this subquery returns any results*.

Since you're using `Exists`, you're not correlating the queries together to do what you want.

I think you're looking for `Subqueries.PropertyIn` instead. Something like this:

```
var subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Session))
    .SetProjection(Property.ForName("Id"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Server", server))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Id"))
    .SetMaxResults(10);

var query = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Session))
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subQuery))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 32768))
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());

var result = (int)query.GetExecutableCriteria(s)
    .UniqueResult();
```

...which will generate SQL that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    count(*) as y0_ 
FROM
    Sessions this_ 
WHERE
    this_.Id in (
        SELECT
            TOP (10) this_0_.Id as y0_ 
        FROM
            Sessions this_0_ 
        WHERE
            this_0_.Server_Id = 2569
        ORDER BY
            this_0_.Id desc
    ) 
    and this_.Status = 32768
```